# Whenever gem cronjob not loading PATH from /etc/environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, bash, cron

In my rails poroject I am using the whenever gem to manage cron-jobs. On of them is this one:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/myhome/analytics && RAILS_ENV=development /bundle exec rake my_rake_job'
```

It doesn't work however with the error `/bin/bash: bundle: command not found`

When I log the `env` from a cronjob to a file I can see amongst other things two environment variables I declare in `/etc/environment` (and nowhere else) but `PATH` comes out as just `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin` as opposed to `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"` which is taken from my `/etc/environment` file.

I mean the short-term dirty solution is to symlink the ruby binaries (ruby, rake, rails, bundle, etc) into `/usr/bin` but that is not a great solution. Why is the cron loading some vars but not `PATH`?

P.S. Here is my `/etc/pam.d/cron` file

```
# The PAM configuration file for the cron daemon

@include common-auth

# Read environment variables from pam_env's default files, /etc/environment
# and /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
session       required   pam_env.so

# In addition, read system locale information
session       required   pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/locale

@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive

# Sets up user limits, please define limits for cron tasks
# through /etc/security/limits.conf
session    required   pam_limits.so
```

Comment: isn't `cron` run as root user? can't you workaround this with `* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'source /etc/environment && cd /home/myhome/analytics && RAILS_ENV=development /bundle exec rake my_rake_job'`

Comment: That's not really feasible because that line is auto-generated by the whenever gem and I have a few dozen cron jobs so adding the source there would mean I'd have to do it for all as well as keep doing it all over when I add another cron job via whenever

Comment: Ok, looks reasonable. Can you check current user id used to run the cron command at least?

Comment: It runs as my user, not root

Comment: ok, workaround would be: create a `bundle` script in `cd /home/myhome/analytics` which sets the paths properly and calls the real `bundle` command with the passed arguments. Hacky but would certainly work, without changing your cron command.

Comment: yeah true that or symlinking the ruby vars into the sourced path. The real question here is why the cron-job loads a couple of custom variables from /etc/environment but not the PATH var that is there too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end adding `source /etc/environment` to the `.bash_profile` (not `.bashrc`) ensures that the cron user loads the right variables and it is working now

Answer (score 1):

Use [adjustable `job_type` Whenever config param](https://github.com/javan/whenever#define-your-own-job-types) to set accurate path to `bundle` in `scheduler.rb`:

`job_type :rake, "cd :path && :environment_variable=:environment /usr/local/bin/bundle exec rake :task --silent :output"`